# Group resource translation files in folder in VS2010 for C#/WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, internationalization

I'm using resource files with strings for internationalization support in a C# WPF application.

I have the files under the folder `Strings` and I access it in code with something like `Strings.MainWindow.SomeStringId`.

Problem is that as the translation files start to grow, that folder beings to contain a huge number of files and it gets easier to screw the pooch by making changes to the wrong file, ending up with German sentences on Russian files.

I'd like to set up the Strings folder to have a sub folder for each locale. I tried changing the "Custom Tool Namespace" option under Properties but to no avail.

Basically this is how it's laid out: http://d.pr/ViwI
And this is how I'd like it to be laid out: http://d.pr/7wsu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another approach.

Instead of Resources/Locale/Bunch_Of_Resources use Resources/Bunch_Of_Folders_One_for_Each_Context/Resources(pt-Pt, en-EN)

It is not perfect. But it will help you organize.

Comment: Not the solution I was hoping for, but after spending some hours trying everything I could think of, I fell back to this option. At least everything's packed in nice and tight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the folders manually, then drag/drop your files into the correct folders.
You can then go through each *.Designer.cs file and change the namespace from "Strings" to "Strings.[locale]".

Comment: When I open the *.Designer.cs file of the resx files there's nothing in there.